# Excel VBA errors only when saving non-XL files, to network, from virtual server

Tags: networking, excel, windows-7, vba

We are using a new box to run our `VBA`

I’m getting some unexpected errors when saving non-excel files, from `Excel`, to the network.

In one program it fails on the following

```
.SaveAs "\\fileserve\department$\x\yyy\xxx\" & RepOperName & FileName & strdate & ".msg", olMSG
```

Showing a run-time error '-2147287008(80030020)'

In another the following just stops on the line `Excel.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat...` with a alert saying document not saved - these are pdf docs it is attempting to save:

```
Dim FullPath_pdf As String
FullPath_pdf = "\\fileserve\department$\x\Statistics\Reporting\zzz\yyy\kkk\Daily Summary.pdf"
Excel.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:=FullPath_pdf, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=2, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Is this likely to be down to the configuration of Excel on the server?
Or will it be more in connection with the configuration of the virtual server and its relationship to the network?

Comment: The error when saving as a .msg is (from winerror.h):

    //
    // MessageId: STG_E_SHAREVIOLATION
    //
    // MessageText:
    //
    // A share violation has occurred.
    //
    #define STG_E_SHAREVIOLATION             _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80030020L)

Does it always occur? Does it occur only on certain folders?

Comment: @Cor_Blimey with the .msg files it always occurs. When you say "Does it occur only on certain folders?" do you suspect that the problem might be connected with the configuration of the folders that I am saving the files into? ...this is not something I considered; how can I test or workaround?

Comment: I just thought that from the error message it could be some sort of access rights exception or something like that. If one operation works fine on some folders but not on others (consistently for the same folders) then a few things could be: e.g. too long a file path, some form of access rights issue. The test really is to see if the error depends on either a certain file or a certain destination. I know little more I am afraid as this is not my area. Good luck though

Comment: @Cor_Blimey Ok - thanks: "too long file path"? I can manually create and save these files to the required destinations so I assume the file path is an acceptable length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem.

I found out I can’t save non-xls files directly to a network path from Excel.
So, my work around was:

1. Export the file locally to any directory
2. Use [ROBOCOPY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robocopy) (since you are using Windows 7) to transfer the file
   across the network

That should work.
Another tip is to make Excel delete the old file before creating a new one.
You could use a Macro like this:

```
Sub DeleteExample()
'You can use this to delete all xml? files in the folder Test
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\Users\Neo\*.xml*"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```